# sorting 2d array with nil value

Tags: sorting, multidimensional-array, transpose

I have an array like this

```
 a=[["address", "US"], ["company", "apple"], ["CEO", ""], ["Website", ""]]
```

I need the first values like ["address", "company", "CEO","Website"]
so what i did was

```
a.transpose
```

I got

```
[["address", "company", "CEO", "Website"], ["US", "apple", "", ""]]
```

Now I need to sort the first array.. and its corresponding value
when I do

```
[["address", "company", "CEO", "Website"], ["US", "apple", "", ""]].sort
```

I get

```
[["US", "apple", "", ""], ["address", "company", "CEO", "Website"]]
```

But what I want is

```
 [["address", "CEO", "company", "Website"], ["US", "", "apple", "" ]
```

If any body could help that'd be gr8!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort it like that:

```
a.sort_by { |e| e[0].downcase } .transpose
```

This first sorts the array with your custom criteria, and **after** that transposes the result, as you need it.

Comment: @Sadiksha Gautam you are welcome, if you have questions about it, just ask. And, you can accept the answer as correct :)